# Read/Write albumart cover type in mp4/m4a with AtomicParsley or any other CLI tool?

Tags: command-line, mp4, tags, album-art, m4a

Is it possible (and how) to read and/or write the cover type of the artwork embedded in mp4/m4a audio with AP? MP4 audio supports 'Front Cover' and 'Back Cover' types, and I can read/set those values with Mp3tag (a windows GUI based program). However, I'm trying to read/set those values with a command line tool, and I've been exploring AtomicParsely which can seemingly do anything regarding mp4/m4a tagging, yet not reading/writing the artwork's cover type it seems (and I'm hoping I'm wrong here).
So anyone knows any better? Help!

Answer (score 0):

MP4art can do that, and it's command line is pretty straightforward.

http://mp4v2.googlecode.com/svn/doc/1.9.0/ToolGuide.html

Example

mp4art --add ACDC.png mysong.m4a