# How to embed cover art into MP4 without errors?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, id3, album-art

I want to add artwork to my MP4 file. How do I do this successfully / without errors?
I've tried these methods with numerous MP4 files, none worked.
If you would like to replicate the errors / bugs, here are the sample [files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/29plag9akl9r1/61375246) I've used for this question.

I've tried the following:

---

1. `ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4`
   as stated by [Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015965/12308353)

with this error:

```
[mp4 @ 0000019ee4852280] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

[ffmpeg 4.2.2](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-4.2.2-win64-static.zip) (Windows build by Zeranoe)

2. `atomicparsley sample.mp4 --artwork sample.png --overWrite`

with no success; [AtomicParsley](https://sourceforge.net/projects/atomicparsley/files/atomicparsley/AtomicParsley%20v0.9.0/AtomicParsley-win32-0.9.0.zip/download)

I get this message when executing the first time:

```
Started writing to temp file.
 Progress: =============================================>100%|
 Finished writing to temp file.
```

Executing the next (nth) time gives this:

```
Updating metadata...   completed.
```

3. Adding artwork through the *GUI Tag Editor* using both available versions: [i686-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-i686-w64-mingw32.exe.zip) & [x86_64-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe.zip)

with no success; it creates a *sample.mp4.bak* [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4kBR.png), even though the [software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Xt8.png) says that the operation was successful

> can't insert any more links, because I got too little rep apparently

4. Mp3tag (mp3tag.de/en)

with no success; I can successfully add the image as a cover, but it's not visible in the File Explorer. After saving it says *Saved tag in 1 of 1 files.* The [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs3ik.png) can been seen in Mp3tag though as if it's applied.

5. Tag&Rename (softpointer.com)

with no success; same story as with Mp3tag, I can apply and it's visible in the app, but not in File Explorer.

6. mp4v2 (https:// code.google.com/archive/p/mp4v2/downloads)

`mp4tags.exe -picture sample.png sample.mp4`

with no success; it executes with no (error)message

I found it on this thread

(https:// forum.videohelp.com/threads/388025-How-to-set-the-thumbnail-of-a-video-clip).

Have used the *updated* version which is the Windows build

(https:// forum.doom9.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=14314&d=1407985798).

7. iTunes

iTunes 12.10.6.2 (Microsoft Store version)

<s>iTunes doesn't load the file into the library.</s> I can run it fine though in QuickTime Player.

I didn't notice the 'Home Videos' tab. Now I can see it in there. I tried to apply the image, and it applied it only inside iTunes... So it's still not working for me.

I tried to convert the MP4 to M4A and then adding it to iTunes. I was **finally** successfully able to change the cover and it was visible in File Explorer. But that's not what I want.

I know for a fact that it's possible, because I've seen pictures on the Internet and YT and different threads where an answer is upvoted.

8. tag

https:// github.com/b4winckler/tag

The description is: *Simple command line audio tag editor*... After having to install millions of libraries and a package manager I was stuck with the compilation of the software, followed all the steps, didn't work.

I've also tried using MP4art as suggested by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130727/12308353) on another issue about this. He didn't include a link to it so I went looking and found another issue about [this](https://superuser.com/q/656481/1127977). One comment recommended MP4art as well, with a link that's dead.

---

I believe I've used some other methods as well but can't think of them right now. Will update if I recall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You write "File Explorer. But that's not what I want." and also uninstalled VLC. Would you please post a screenshot of the software where the artwork is missing?

Comment: I didn't say that, so I can't. I said that it IS visible in e.g Mp3tag, but only as a M4A & M4V format.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "only as a M4A & M4V format" - M4V is not mentioned in your question, please add it there.
My guess is, that your real problem is not the part of adding the artwork - but the software where you want to display it. So that everyone can be sure, please post the screenshot that shows your issue. If you are talking about Windows Explorer with K-Lite's thumbnailer, please mention this important info in your question. And please add screenshots of the thumbnailer settings (using CodecTweakTool.exe Misc/Thumbnails/Options). So an issue with Icaros or Microsoft?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I got it solved. In the Codec Tweak Tool under Misc/Thumbnails the checkbox for .mp4 was unchecked. After checking it and saving the settings it finally showed the thumbnail. The reason I didn't think about checking those settings is because 1. I had no idea that there's settings for that and 2. I tried the VLC thumbnailer and it didn't work either. I'm so glad I finally got it to work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [*Codec Tweak Tool*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4snnj.png) under Miscellaneous > Thumbnails the checkbox for .mp4 was unchecked. After checking it and saving the settings it finally showed the thumbnail.

The Tweak Tool is installed with [**K-Lite Codec Pack**](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). There are different editions available, I use the Standard edition so I can't talk for the other ones.

Credits for finding the solution: [Furty](https://superuser.com/users/1165405/furty) as a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1544737/how-to-embed-cover-art-into-mp4-without-errors?noredirect=1#comment2348563_1544737)

Answer (score 1):

I have used iTunes in the past to add album art to mp3 files. I just tested with a movie mp4 file and it worked fine for me. This is how you would do it. Also, I am assuming the OS is Windows here but iTunes should work on Linux too.

By the way, you may get a notification upon starting iTunes to automatically get artwork from the internet. I usually choose No Thanks for this option as we are trying to set the artwork manually.

[image: No Thanks]

Once iTunes is open, it may be Music by default. Click the dropdown menu and select Movies. You can then drag and drop your file into iTunes.

[image: Movies]

You may not see it right away. If that's the case, go back to Music and then come back to Movies again. It doesn't seem to refresh automatically every time. Your file will now be in the Home Movies section of the Library. Right click the video and select Video Info.

[image: Video Info]

Now you can add art in the Artwork tab. Click Add Artwork and browse for the image file you want to add.

[image: Artwork]

You can delete the movie from the iTunes library if you want, it won't delete the actual source file in Windows. I also deleted the art image file just to check and the mp4 still retains the cover art in Windows.

[image: Windows]

Comment: I've tried that already (didn't update my question with it, my bad) with again no success. iTunes doesn't load the file to the library. I've tried with a different MP4 as well, didn't work. I'm using iTunes version: 12.10.6.2 (from Microsoft Store).

Have you tried the sample file linked in my question?

Comment: Interesting, I was able to add it through iTunes fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJauv.png I am on the same version from the Microsoft Store. Are you sure it wasn't added? After dragging it in, it won't show up automatically. You may need to switch out to Music or something and switch back to Movies before the Home Videos option appears. If it still doesn't work then try downloading the version of the sample files you uploaded in case somehow they were changed.

Comment: I didn't notice the 'Home Videos' tab. Now I can see it in there. I tried to apply the image, and it applied it only inside iTunes... So it's still not working for me. I tried to convert the MP4 to M4A and then adding it to iTunes. I was successfully able to change the cover and it was visible in File Explorer. But I want to apply it to MP4... which apparently is possible. Have any idea what's wrong? I did as you said, downloaded the samples again that I uploaded.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what would be going wrong then. If you are able to see it in iTunes and it works for M4A, then it isn't an issue of the file being read-only or with permissions. How do you verify the cover art is updated? Like is the thumbnail updated in Windows for the M4A but not the MP4?

Comment: Yes! Exactly...

Comment: I'm wondering if it's just Windows... Does restarting the PC help at all? Lol thought I'd ask. Do you have VLC player installed? If you open the file with VLC and go to Tools > Media Information, you should see the art there.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting, it doesn't fix it. I already deleted VLC, don't like it, no offense. I prefer 'K-Lite Codec Pack' Standard, which uses MPC-HC. I can see the artworks in Mp3tag though: http://www.mediafire.com/view/oxuz0exjjn7m4k5/success-with-m4a.png/file